# Изменение данных учётной записи пользователя по кнопке

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Всем привет. Есть страница, на которой есть две формы и кнопка. Как зарегистрированному пользователю изменить свой логин, например?  PHP выдаёт предупреждение:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

и дальше ничего не происходит. Прошу помощи :( Пример кода страницы ниже

```
<?
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $login_edit = $_POST['login_edit'];
        $data_edit = $_POST['data_edit'];
    }

    include ("bd.php");

    $sql_edit = "UPDATE users SET $login_edit where login = '$login'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql_edit) or trigger_error(mysql_error(). " in ". $sql_edit);
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
        echo "ok";
    }
?>
```

Comment: @RogatnevNikita Ели вы считаете, что вопрос не дубликат  и его надо переоткрытъ, то оставте комментарий - почему вы так считаете?

Answer (score 0):

> `$sql_edit = "UPDATE users SET $login_edit where login = '$login'";`

Ошибка в самом запросe, `SET` - нужно указать имя колонки и ему присвоить значение:

`$sql_edit = "UPDATE users SET login = '$login_edit' where login = '$login'";`

`where login = '$login'` - так лучше не делать, если `login` не является УНИКАЛЬНЫМ, скорее всего у вас уникальный `ID` вот лучше по нему и выбирать.

`where id = '$id'`

`$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($res);` - ошибка в том, что fetch_array принимает результат от `SELECT`-запроса.

Для `UPDATE` делаем проверку так:

```
if ($res) {
    if (mysql_affected_rows() >= 0) {
        echo "ok";
    }
}
```

Comment: Изменил SQL запрос. Да, уникальный только id пользователя(это первичный ключ). Запрос fetch_array сделал через проверку условным оператором. Ничего не изменилось, так и осталась ошибка с этим параметром :(

Comment: @SnoopDoggyDog поправил проверку на UPDATE

Comment: Очень странно. Ошибка осталась та же самая, mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, строка 9. Но у меня этой строчки даже нету в файле. Такое бывало раньше, помогала чистка кэша браузера. Сейчас даже это не помогло :D

Comment: @SnoopDoggyDog посмотрите внимательно текст ошибки, какой файл? может она `include ("bd.php");` там?